# how to display tax percentage instead of tax name in invoice odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8

I'm trying to display tax percentage instead of their name in **accounting > customer invoices**
[image]

I want to have the percentage from **accounting > configuration > taxes > taxes**
[image]
I don't know how to achieve this

Comment: The [name_get](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/account.py#L1957) function was redefined to use the description (Code) field or the name field. You can override it to use another field (a computed percentage field, for example) or the combination of the tax name and percentage.

Comment: thank you @Kenly for respond im still learning odoo and there a lot i don't understand yet so please if can you explain more with example will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [name_get](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/models.py#L1673) returns a textual representation for the records in `self`.
By default, this is the value of the `display_name` field.

The method was redefined in [account.tax](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/account.py#L1957) to use the description (Code) field or the name field. In the following example, we will override the same method to show the tax amount percentage.

```py
class AccountTax(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.tax'

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        res = []
        for record in self:
            percentage = int(record.amount * 100)
            name = str(percentage) + "%"
            res.append((record.id, name))
        return res
```

***Edit:***

To use the same representation in invoice report (which uses the [name](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/views/report_invoice.xml#L72) field for tax name), just call the `name_get` function to get the display name.

***Example:*** Inherit invoice report to use the display name instead of tax name

```
<template id="report_invoice_document" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
    <xpath expr="//tbody[hasclass('invoice_tbody')]/tr/td[5]/span" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="t-esc">', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name_get()[0][1], l.invoice_line_tax_id))</attribute>
     </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: im sorry @Kenly for bothering you the code  work perfectly but when i try to print the invoice i have the name of the tax not the the percentage can you help and thank you

Comment: No problem. The invoice report uses the tax name (name field) and you need to alter the invoice report document template to use the display name. Check my edit